# How to use same model for two tables. Or db best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

In a MVC app I´m setting up a database with multiple tables that got the same structure and I want to use the same model for all of them instead of having to create a new model for each. When trying to use the same model creating multiple tables I get the following error:

> "Multiple object sets per type are not supported"

Is it somehow possible to use the same model to create two tables?

I´m building a db with equitys historical prices. And the idea is one table per equity.

```
 Stock1                       Stock2
 -Date                        -Date
 -Price                       -Price
```

Or is best practice in db-design to have all data with the same structure in one table and then use annother table to connect data to the parent?

```
Instruments              Data
-StockId                 -Date
-StockName               -Price
                         -StockId(FK)
```

Code:

```
//Models for tables

 public class Instruments
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }


public class Equity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Instruments")]
    public int InstrumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Instruments Instruments { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
}

//Code to create tables when running "add-migration"
public DbSet<Instruments> Instruments { get; set; }
public DbSet<Equity> Stock1 { get; set; }
public DbSet<Equity> Stock2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why do you need `Stock2`? `Stock1` is good enough to store data for all stocks (1,2,3..n). Add a StockName/StockId (foriegn key to stock table)

Comment: Is that the right way/best practice?

Comment: Yes, it is. Creating anew table for new Stocks is not a flexible approach. It requires you to change your code. It is much easier to have one single table.

Comment: Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Table per Stock is a bad Idea.

You can store data for all stocks in the `Stock1` property of your DbContext class. Add a property/column to distinguish the stock name/StockId to your Equity table.

If you are using `StockI`, create a Stock table and `StockId` in your `Equity` table will have a foreign key connection to the Stock table.

```
public class Stock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { set;get; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Equity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Instruments")]
    public int InstrumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Instruments Instruments { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }

    public int StockId { set;get;}
    public virtual Stock Stock { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your DbContext class, you will only have one property of `DbSet<Equity>` type. You can access all Equity records via this or filter it based on your need (ex : Get records for a specific Stock)

```
public DbSet<Equity> Equities { get; set; }
```

To get data for specific Stock, You will usually use a filter. For example,

```
var stockIdOfMsft = 24; 
var msftEquities = db.Equities.Where(a=>a.StockId == stockIdOfMsft).ToList();
```

Or

```
var msftEquities = db.Equities.Where(a=>a.Stock.Ticker == "MSFT").ToList();
```